# Namenode cannot start

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade HDFS from 1.2.1 to version 2.6. However, whenever I run start-dfs.sh -upgrade command, I get the below error:

hduser@Cluster1-NN:/usr/local/hadoop2/hadoop-2.6.0/etc_bkp/hadoop$ $HADOOP_NEW_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh -upgrade

15/05/17 12:45:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

**Starting namenodes on [nn]**

**Error: Please specify one of --hosts or --hostnames options and not both.**

nn: starting datanode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-Cluster1-NN.out
dn1: starting datanode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-Cluster1-DN1.out
dn2: starting datanode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-Cluster1-DN2.out

**Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]**

**Error: Please specify one of --hosts or --hostnames options and not both.**

Please let me know if any of you experts have come across such error.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem on Arch Linux with newly installed Hadoop 2.7.1. I'm not sure whether my case is the same as yours or not, but my experience should help. I just comment out the line `HADOOP_SLAVES=/etc/hadoop/slaves` in `/etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh` and re-login. Both accessing HDFS and running streaming jobs work for me.

The cause is that the Arch-specific script `/etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh` declares the `$HADOOP_SLAVES` environment variable. And in `start-dfs.sh`, `hadoop-daemons.sh` is called with `--hostnames` arguments. This confuses `libexec/hadoop-config.sh`.

You may want to type `echo $HADOOP_SLAVES` as the hadoop user. If there are non-empty outputs, check your `.bashrc` and/or other shell startup scripts. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is short of some hadoop library.Can you show the detail information of namenode logs?